# Issue with getting the data from url Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have an issue with the below service.

```
{
    "DataTable": [
                  {
                      "EmpTable": [
                                        {
                                            "Name": "Rakesh",
                                            "Finaldata": "5",
                                            "data": "One Year Free",
                                            "heading": "HR",
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Name": "Roshan",
                                            "Finaldata": "1",
                                            "data": "1 Month",
                                            "heading": "Software",

                                        },
                                        {
                                            "Name": "Ramesh",
                                            "Finaldata": "5",
                                            "data": "3 Month",
                                            "heading": "Admin",
                                        },

                                        ]
                  }
                  ]
}
```

Only getting the details of Ramesh from the above output, Remaining data doesn't display in my table view. Below is my code what i have tried from the above service. Please help to find out the issue. TIA

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return _empArr.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    EmpCell *cell = (MembershipCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MembershipCell" owner:self options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                cell =  (EmpCell *) currentObject;

            }
        }
    }

    profiledict = [_empArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for (NSDictionary *temp in profiledict) {

    cell.lblName.text = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.lblFinaldata.text = [temp objectForKey:@"Finaldata"];
    cell.lbldata.text = [temp objectForKey:@"data"];
    cell.lblheading.text = [temp objectForKey:@"heading"];

}

    return cell;
}



- (void)jsonData:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict
{
    NSMutableArray *jsonArr;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict;
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];


    jsonArr=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"DataTable"];

    if (![jsonArr isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {
        _empArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i=0; i<jsonArr.count; i++) {
            dict=[jsonArr objectAtIndex:i];
            [_empArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"EmpTable"]];


        }
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {


        [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Something went wrong"];

        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}
```

Comment: What is that last loop for? You'll only end up setting the values from the last iterated `temp`.

Comment: You are adding only the last object in the last for loop. You are overriding it on each iteration. You should create a new object inside the loop and then add it to the array.

Comment: You are adding Whole `EmpTable ` array as an object in array. So there is only one object in array. Thats why only one cell will be added on tableView. Try to extract array objects from `EmpTable ` array.

Comment: could you please ellobarate with the code.TIA

Comment: no need of loop here `for (int i=0; i<jsonArr.count; i++) {  you can directly add dict=[jsonArr objectAtIndex:0];
            [_empArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"EmpTable"]];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding Whole `EmpTable` array as an object in array. So there is only one object in array. Thats why only one cell will be added on `tableView`. Try to extract array objects from `EmpTable` array.

In `- (void)jsonData:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict` method

Replace

`[_empArr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"EmpTable"]];`

with

`[_empArr addObjectsFromArray:[dict objectForKey:@"EmpTable"]];`

and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Replace

```
profiledict = [_empArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

for (NSDictionary *temp in profiledict) {

    cell.lblName.text = [temp objectForKey:@"Name"];
    cell.lblFinaldata.text = [temp objectForKey:@"Finaldata"];
    cell.lbldata.text = [temp objectForKey:@"data"];
    cell.lblheading.text = [temp objectForKey:@"heading"];

}
```

With

```
profiledict = [_empArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.lblName.text = [profiledict objectForKey:@"Name"];
cell.lblFinaldata.text = [profiledict objectForKey:@"Finaldata"];
cell.lbldata.text = [profiledict objectForKey:@"data"];
cell.lblheading.text = [temp objectForKey:@"heading"];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`_empArr.count` will always be 1 because you have only one "EmpTable" object inside. Even if you fix that, then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`'s `for (NSDictionary *temp in profiledict)` you cycle through all the array and never stop, so each time it will be the last object to fill your cell fields.

Comment: I don't understand. could you please ellobarate with the code @shebuka .TIA